# Facing an issue with applying configuration for Alertmanager to send rmail notification on kubernetes(EKS) cluster when alert rules are triggered

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

‍♂️Hello everyone, I'm currently working on configuration for **Alertmanager to send email notifications** , and I've encountered a problem. I've set up an EKS cluster and installed the **Prometheus Operator** using Helm with the command

`$  helm install monitoring prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -n monitoring`

Additionally, I've configured the alert rules in Prometheus. Now, I want to set up the **Alertmanager configuration to receive email notifications whenever any alert rule is triggered.**

I have created a configuration file for Alertmanager, but when I try to apply it to the cluster, I get an error.

here is my  **alert-manager-config.yaml **

```html
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1beta1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata: 
  name: main-rules-alert-config
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  route:
    receivers: 'email'
    repeatInterval: 30m
    routes:
    - matchers:
      - name: alertname
        value: CPUisBurning
    - matchers:
      - name: alertname
        value: AppPodRestart
      repeatInterval: 5m
  receivers:
  - name: 'email'
    emailConfigs:
    - to: 'myemail@gmail.com'
      from: 'myemail@gmail.com'
      smarthost: 'smtp_host:587'
      authUsername: 'mymail@gmail.com'
      authIdentity: 'mymail@gmail.com'
      authPassword: 
        name: mail-pass
        key: pass
```

Please see this image which containe error message.
[image: error message]

it says that ensure CRDs are installed first but all the CRDs are alredy present. you can see that in image. even I've tried with **v1alpha1** then it says syntax error about (receivers) but I took referance from official doc and created above file.

here is the link of Official doc: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/rest_api/monitoring_apis/alertmanagerconfig-monitoring-coreos-com-v1beta1.html

I've been struggling with this issue for about 4 hours, and I'm seeking help to resolve it. If anyone has experienced a similar situation and found a solution, I'd greatly appreciate your help with this problem. Thank you!